Apache rewrite rule ignoring everything after / for one rule
I am running a webserver behind a Cloudflare load balancer and a redirect I have set up in Apache isn't working. I have two https ports running on the server, 443 and 8443. Most traffic is for the 443 port, but I have one subfolder on the URL that I want to be accessed on port 8443 specifically. I have Apache vhost rules that (truncated down) look like this:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName my.url.is.here

    <LocationMatch "^(?=/subfolder-to-check)/[^/]*">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://my.url.is.here:8443/$1 [R=301,L]
#       RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8443/$1 [R=301,L]
    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName my.url.is.here

    <LocationMatch "^(?!/subfolder-to-check)/[^/]*">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://my.url.is.here:443/$1 [R=301,L]
#       RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:443/$1 [R=301,L]
    </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>

The commented out line is because initially Cloudflare wasn't picking up the SERVER_NAME variable correctly, so I just hardcoded the URL instead. This works insofar as it is picking up the part of the URL after the / to apply the relevant LocationMatch rule correctly, but seems to ignore the $1 part of the rewrite rule for the URL it is forwarding to for the 443-to-8443 rule only.
If I go to https://my.url.is.here/subfolder-to-check , it is sending me to https://my.url.is.here instead of https://my.url.is.here:8443/subfolder-to-check , though I can access that subfolder on that URL if I do specify the correct port first (i.e. going directly to https://my.url.is.here:8443/subfolder-to-check works).
In summary:

Port 8443 to 443 with subfolder-to-check works as expected (by not getting a match)
Port 8443 to 443 with any other folder works as expected (by removing the :8443 from the URL)
Port 443 to 8443 with subfolder-to-check doesn't work
Port 443 to 8443 with any other folder works as expected (by not getting a match)

Matching the URL to be edited seems to work correctly, where you are being sent does not. Where am I going wrong?

Do you have other rules inside the <LocationMatch> container? What rules have you "truncated down"? Conflicts with other rules are a very common source of error. "Cloudflare wasn't picking up the SERVER_NAME variable" - not sure what Cloudflare has to do with this, or even what you mean exactly? The SERVER_NAME server variable contains the requested hostname (by default) unless UseCanonicalName is set.

There are no other rules inside the <LocationMatch> container. I've removed items from the vhost entry like SSL cert paths, etc that aren't relevant to the location matching. Ignore what I said about the SERVER_NAME variable as well, we thought initially the Host Header entry on Cloudflare was messing with it but it turns out it's doing the same thing regardless.
